# JQuery mobile header, footer disappear on timeout, reappear on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, timeout, hide

I would like to set things up on my mobile app so that the header and footer toolbars behave like the video controls in Netflix: that is, they appear on load; disappear after a few seconds; then reappear when the screen is clicked.  The default behaviour for these classes in JQM is for them to appear on load, then disappear/reappear on subsequent clicks.
I could do it something like this:

1. Have the bars appear on load
2. Set a timeout to hide the bars, so:

   ```
   window.setTimeout(function(){ 
     $("#footer").hide();
     $("#header").hide();
   }, 3000);
   ```
3. Bind an event to the window so that a click anywhere within it when the bars are hidden has them reappear; unbind the event until the timeout kicks in
4. Rinse and repeat
   There are various refinements one could put in (have the bars disappear if you click before the timeout, etc).

Sounds simple enough.  Turns out to be difficult, because it appears to conflict with JQM's own way of having headers etc appear and disappear on mouse clicks.  So adding this function, attaching a click event to bring back the headers, leads to erratic behaviour, with the headers appearing and disappeariing in random ways:

```
   function resetTimer () {
       $(document).bind("click",function(){
           $("#footer").show();
           $("#header").show();
           window.setTimeout(function(){
               $("#footer").hide();
               $("#header").hide();
              resetTimer();
          }, 5000);
        });
    }

    window.setTimeout(function(){ 
       $("#footer").hide();
       $("#header").hide();
       resetTimer();
     }, 5000);
```

Any ideas? surely there is a better way to do this than this draconian fiddling with global windows and document events. If I remove the attributes `data-role="header"` etc from the divs holding the header and footer, everything appears fine -- but I lose the automatic positioning and other behaviours offered by JQM, which would mean a painful reconstruction of their coding. But I can't find in the JQM documents etc anyway to do this...

Comment: Have you tried setting data-tap-toggle="false" on the header and footer?

Comment: worked! perfect!!  I feel silly for not trying this.  Seems this nicely disables the default JQM treatment of click events leaving my code to do its stuff nicely.  great!